# key 112 (char 'p') not in lookup table in Biostrings after calling getPromoterSeq (GenomicFeatures package)

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, genomicranges

Failed when trying to get promoter sequence from TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene by getPromoterSeq (GenomicFeatures package)

```
library(TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene)
library(BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19)
library(Homo.sapiens)

promoter.gr = transcriptsBy(TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene, by='gene')[11338]
promoter.seq = getPromoteSeq(promoter.gr, Hsapiens, upstream=3000, downstream=0)
promoter.seq
```

It come out as below:

```
DNAStringSetList of length 1
Error in .Call2("new_CHARACTER_from_XStringSet", x, xs_dec_lkup(x), PACKAGE='Biostrings'):
key 112 (char 'p') not in lookup table.
```

I search other discussions on this error. It seems there is non T, C, G, A sequence, mostly a 'p' in the sequence file when people trying to load the sequence file. While here I did not even provide sequence locally, it's all from the packages.